# How to deal with large data sets for analytics, and varying numbers of columns'?

Tags: php, mysql, analytics

I'm building an analytics system for a mobile application and have had some difficulty deciding how to store and process large amounts of data.

Each row will represent a 'view' (like a web page) and store some fixed attributes, like user agent and date. Additionally, each view may have a varying number of extra attributes, which relate to actions performed or content identifiers.

I've looked at Amazon SimpleDb which handles the varying number of attributes well, but has no support for GROUP BY and doesn't seem to perform well when COUNTing rows either. Generating a monthly graph with 30 data points would require a query for each day per dataset.

MySQL handles the COUNT and GROUP modifiers much better but additional attributes require storage in a link table and a JOIN to retrieve views where attributes match a given value, which isn't very fast. 5.1's partitioning feature may help speed things up a bit.

What I have gathered from a lot of reading and profiling queries on the aforementioned systems is that ultimately all of the data needs to be aggregated and stored in tables for quick report generation.

Have I missed anything obvious in my research and is there a better way to do this than use MySQL? It doesn't feel like the right task for the job, but I can't find anything capable of both GROUP/COUNT queries and a flexible table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping it in MySQL: If the amount of writes are limited  / reads are more common, and the data is relatively simple (i.e: you can predict possible characters), you could try to use a text/blob column in the main table, which is updated with comma separated values or key/value pairs with an `AFTER INSERT / UPDATE` trigger on the join table. You keep the actual data in a separate table, so searching for MAX's / specific 'extra' attributes can still be done relatively fast, but retrieving the complete dataset for one of your 'views' would be a single row in the main table, which you can split into the separate values with the script / application you're using, relieving much of the stress on the database itself.

The downside of this is a tremendous increase in cost of updates / inserts in the join table: every alteration of data would require a query on all related data for a record, and a second insert into the 'normal' table, something like

```
UPDATE join_table
JOIN main_table
ON main_table.id = join_table.main_id
SET main_table.cache  = GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(join_table.key,'=',join_table.value) SEPARATOR ';')
WHERE join_table.main_id = 'foo' GROUP BY main_table.id`).
```

However, as analytics data goes it usually trails somewhat, so possibly not every update has to trigger an update in cache, just a daily cronscript filling the cache with yesterdays data could do.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made my question clearer. The system will be write heavy, with potentially millions of rows each day.

Comment: Question is: is a record updated, or static for the day? Also: analytics systems are most commonly done with parsing logs once every X time (in almost any case, just logging to file is incredibly faster then any database, sql or nosql), not 'live'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where you want to store the data once and read it over and over. Further I think that you'd wish the queries to be preprocessed instead of needing to be calculated on every go.

My suggestion for you is to store your data in CouchDB for the following reasons:

- Its tables are structureless
- Its queries are pre-processed
- Its support for map-reduce allows your queries to handle group by
- It has a REST service access model which lets you connect from pretty much anything that handle HTTP requests

You may find this suggestion a little out there considering how new CouchDB is. However I'd suggest for you to read about it because personally I think running a CouchDB database is sweet and lightweight. More light weight than MySQL

Comment: CouchDB looks very interesting for this purpose, particularly the way that views are stored on disk!

Comment: Then try to use MongoDB, it also have all features of CouchDB, probably except build-in REST interface.